# How to add an RSS logo to my blogs header?

Tags: css, rss, themes, logo, icon

I have started a new site ([here](http://www.forex-bloggers.com/)), I want to add the theme a RSS icon/logo on the top right of the theme (like in [this theme](http://www.r-bloggers.com/)).

What is the best way for doing that?  (PHP/CSS wise)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want some code to be added to the `#title` element. You can do this, [as Sorich said](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2742/how-to-add-an-rss-logo-to-my-blogs-header/2745#2745), by copying the `header.php` file and just adding it there, but you could also try to add it in the footer and then using Javascript move it to the correct element. This might survive theme upgrades better, but is maybe not so user-friendly (the image appears just after the page has been loaded, giving a strange flash).

The code you need is simple, let's take the example you gave:

```
<p>
    <a href="<?php echo bloginfo('rss2_url'); ?>">
        <img style="vertical-align:middle" src="http://www.r-bloggers.com/wp-content/themes/black-lucas/images/rss.png" alt="Subscribe to R-bloggers">
        RSS Feed
    </a>
</p>
```

Of course, you would copy the image to your own server and change the path. You can check the styles used on the page, using a good web inspector/debugging tool (like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)).

Answer (score 1):

Generally:

- Some themes provide hooks or widgets areas that you can use
- For the theme which does not provide them, you can create a child theme or edit templates files.

With the theme you are using on your blog, there is no hook. So, I would recommend creating a [Child Theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes). The benefit is that your modifications will not be overwritten during a theme upgrade.

Steps:

1. Create a child theme
2. Copy `header.php` from the theme directory to the child theme
3. Modify the new `header.php` file in the child theme directory

See the codex for [details about the feeds URLs](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Feeds).

Comment: Thanks Sorich,  But what (css/php) code do I use to add the logo in the correct place?

Answer (score 0):

It depends. There is number of ways theme can be customized:

- it can include ready-made widget areas or admin control panel;
- it can include set of hooks to insert content in different areas;
- templates can be directly edited;
- etc.

Most basic way to modify header is `header.php` template, called by `get_header()` function.

But without seeing the internals the only person who can properly answer this is theme's developer.